# When running npm test, is it necessary to place "CI=true" in the beginning of the test command?

Tags: testing, npm, package.json, npm-scripts, react-scripts

My package.json contains

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom"
       }
```

What is the difference if I rewrite the code as

```
    "scripts": {
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom CI=true"
    }
```

Will the unit test fail when built?

Comment: I'm also interested.

Comment: I believe CI=true is added so the tests aren't interactive and complete automatically. If you add CI=true to the end, your automated build will likely be stuck waiting for the test run to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The CI=true at the beginning of the line is a way to set environment variables only for the command on the same line.

If you run this on the CLI, this would also work:

```
export CI=true
react-scripts test
```

But all following commands will also have the "CI" environment variable set.
To avoid this, you can write it in the same line:

```
CI=true react-scripts test
```

But if you put the CI=true at the end, it will be passed to the **react-scripts** command as a parameter, which is most likely ignored.

In all these examples, **react-scripts** is the command which is executed, even when it's not the first word in the line!